# Config generic hub in startup ASP.NET Core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a generic hub:

```cs
public class SendRequestToUserSignalR<T, HubContext> where T : class where HubContext : Hub
{
    private readonly IUserConnectionManager userConnectionManager;
    private readonly IHubContext<HubContext> hubContext;

    public SendRequestToUserSignalR(IUserConnectionManager userConnectionManager , IHubContext<HubContext> hubContext)
    {
        this.userConnectionManager = userConnectionManager;
        this.hubContext = hubContext;
    }
}
```

And I need to set it in the startup:

```cs
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
    routes.MapHub<SendRequestToUserSignalR<,>>("/sendRequest");
});
```

But it doesn't work and I get this error:

> Using the generic type 'SendRequestToUserSignalR' requires 2 type arguments

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, your configuration is totally wrong.

You don't need to define generic class as hub:

```
public class SendRequestToUserSignalR : Hub
{
    public SendRequestToUserSignalR(...services)
    {
        // code goes here...
    }
}
```

In the `ConfigureServices` method, you need to start the service:

```
services.AddSignalR();
```

In the `Configure` method, you map that hub inside `UseEndpoints` method:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapHub<SendRequestToUserSignalR>("/sendRequest");
});
```

**Note:** `app.UseSignalR` method is obsolete in asp.net core version 3.x

Comment: This works great until the hub has a dependency, i.e. on MyApi that is being created via SimpleInjector or other DI container.